# INSERT to a table with a sub query

Tags: sql, insert, triggers

Can I do this in SQL 2005?

```
SELECT 'C'+inserted.exhid AS ExhId,inserted.exhname AS ExhName,inserted.exhid AS RefID INTO mytable FROM inserted 
    WHERE inserted.altname IS NOT NULL
```

It won't work if the table exists, but will create the table if it is non-existent. How do I get it to insert into an existing table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

like this

```
INSERT INTO mytable
SELECT 'C'+inserted.exhid AS ExhId,inserted.exhname AS ExhName,
 inserted.exhid AS RefID  FROM inserted 
    WHERE inserted.altname IS NOT NULL
```

you also don't need the aliases in this case

Answer (score 3):

SQLMenace's answer is correct.  But to add to it, I would suggest that it is  a good practice to explicitly list your columns that you are inserting into in the event the table structure/column order ever changes, that way your proc stands a better change of working consistently.

```
INSERT INTO mytable ( 
ExhId, 
ExhName, 
RefID) 
SELECT 'C'+inserted.exhid,
inserted.exhname, 
inserted.exhid 
FROM inserted 
WHERE inserted.altname IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

To insert into an existing table, use `INSERT INTO` instead of `SELECT INTO